# Issue in Writing the contents of a variable to a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the `SPF records` of a `domains` and the domains are read from a file.When i am trying to get the spf contents and write it to a file and the code gives me the results of last domain got from input file.

```
Example `Input_Domains.txt`

blah.com
box.com
marketo.com
```

The output,I get is only for the `marketo.com`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket
import dns.resolver
import re


def getspf (domain):
   answers = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'TXT')
   for rdata in answers:
     for txt_string in rdata.strings:
       if txt_string.startswith('v=spf1'):
         return txt_string.replace('v=spf1','')

with open('Input_Domains.txt','r') as f:
     for line in f:
        full_spf=getspf(line.strip())
my_file=open("out_spf.txt","w")
my_file.write(full_spf)
my_file.close()
```

How can i solve this by writing all the spf contents of domains which i got  it to file,Any suggestions please ?

Comment: You are only performing a single write, how do you expect to get anything other than the last entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are rewriting `full_spf` all the time so only last value is stored

```
with open('Input_Domains.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        full_spf=getspf(line.strip())
```

**Modification:**

```
with open('Input_Domains.txt','r') as f:
    full_spf=""
    for line in f:
        full_spf+=getspf(line.strip())+"\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [a generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) inside your `with` block, instead of a regular `for` loop:

```
full_spf = '\n'.join(getspf(line.strip()) for line in f)
```

This will grab all the lines at once, do your custom `getspf` operations to them, and then join them with newlines between.

The advantage to doing it this way is that conceptually you're doing a single transformation over the data. There's nothing inherently "loopy" about taking a block of data and processing it line-by-line, since it could be done in any order, all lines are independent. By doing it with a generator expression you are expressing your algorithm as a single transformation-and-assignment operation.

Edit: Small oversight, since `join` needs a list of strings, you'll have to return at least an empty string in every case from your `getspf` function, rather than defaulting to `None` when you don't return anything.